# Customising markdown syntax highlighting in Geany

Tags: syntax-highlighting, markdown, geany

I'm using Geany 1.23.1 on Lubuntu 13.10.

I've copied over `filetypes.markdown` from `/usr/share/geany` to `~/.config/geany/filedefs`.

`filetypes.markdown` has the following content:

```
# For complete documentation of this file, please see Geany's main documentation
[styling]
# Edit these in the colorscheme .conf file instead
default=default
strong=string_3
emphasis=string_4
header1=keyword_1
header2=keyword_1
header3=keyword_1
header4=keyword_1
header5=keyword_1
header6=keyword_1
ulist_item=tag_unknown
olist_item=tag_unknown
blockquote=tag_unknown
strikeout=tag_unknown
hrule=tag_unknown
link=keyword_1
code=attribute_unknown
codebk=attribute_unknown

[settings]
# default extension used when saving files
extension=mkd

# sort tags by appearance
symbol_list_sort_mode=1
```

Why is the third line present: **# Edit these in the colorscheme .conf file instead**?

What is wrong with editing `filetypes.markdown` itself? I would think that, at least from a user's perspective, editing `~/.config/geany/filedefs/filetypes.markdown` (or any other filetypes file) would be preferable to editing a `.conf` file (in `~/.config/geany/colorschemes`) as suggested because editing a `.conf` file would affect all filetypes not just `filetype.markdown`.

Comment: Total guess but is it one of those situations where the filetypes.markdown can be managed by a package, and customizations are kept in a separate file?

Comment: I've just begun getting used to using Geany. I try to read the manual for help first but I couldn't get my doubt cleared up. Just as an example, we use ` and ` to enclose inline code in markdown. The original `filetype.markdown` has "code=attribute_unknown". Then I look at the appropriate `.conf` in `~/.config/geany/colorschemes` (Dark Solarized theme for geany: http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) and see "attribute_unknown=attribute,bold" and "attribute=keyword_1" and "keyword_1=keyword" and "keyword=#0086b3;;true".

Comment: @slm My point is that if I edit the theme's .conf  to change "keyword=#0086b3;;true" to something else, all other file types, html, css, js, py, will have the changed keyword. Whereas, I can simply edit `filetypes.markdown` in my home and not affect any other file type's appearance. Which I why I'm trying to understand the comment line I referred to in my question. _Editing filetypes.markdown doesn't seem to break anything so far._

Answer (score 1):

The `filetypes.*` configuration are overriding styling rules defined in `colorschemes` files.

In your personal `filetypes.*` configuration, if you use a *common named_style* (they are in [named_styles] section of `colorschemes` files), you override this style and when you change `colorscheme`, you may have unexpected results.

If you create a *personal named_style*, you override nothing but you have to add it in each `colorschemes` to ensure that the visual result is compatible with it.

See Geany's documentation

- *Filetype configuration*:

  - [[styling] section](https://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#styling-section)
  - [[named_styles] section](https://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#named-styles-section)
- [Color schemes](https://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#color-schemes-dialog)